# where to put shadowbox modal CSS in SASS SMACSS

Tags: sass, oocss, smacss

i am new to `SMACSS`. i am using sass and i want to import the shadowbox modal `css` using `SMACSS`.
I am a bit confused as where to put the `shadowbox.css` file.I mean in BASE or somewhere else.
I read the documentation but it still is quite confusing.
please support.
thanks.

Comment: Is there a technical question here?  If your question is "how do I format my code according to someone else's arbitrary rules", then this question is off topic.

Comment: @cimmanon,just to avoid misunderstanding, in SMACSS u should place CSS rules in one of 5 categories (BASE, MODULE, STATE, LAYOUT, THEME). If i got right the question is what category should be used to place shadowbox.css content

Comment: @Evgeniy Sounds like arbitrary rules to me.  No different than tabs vs spaces, general formatting, or naming conventions.  There's no technical problem here, it's a case of "I don't know what to call my stuff".

Comment: @cimmanon, but to be honest, its difficult to find really technical question in thread about naming convention:) in one hand you are right, but on the over its pretty difficult to ask different type of question in this tag then 'how to name my selector' and 'where to place my css rule'

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add sub-class in `MODULES` for `modal` as you 'extend' parent module with extra features.

```
.modal-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

and use it in HTML like

```
<div class="modal modal-shadow">
    something
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ?